# A representation is semisimple if its restriction to a subgroup of index prime to Char(F) is semisimple

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup whose index is prime to $p$. Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ whose restriction to $H$ is semisimple. Prove that $V$ is semisimple.

Comment: "prime to $p$" means "not divisible by $p$"?

Comment: @rschwieb: It's short for saying the index and $p$ are coprime, which for prime $p$ is equivalent to not-divisible-by-$p$.

Comment: @anon I gathered that much, I just have never heard "prime to $p$" used in place of "coprime with $p$"

Comment: I can deduce a few things, but I confess I don't know much about modular forms. Is there any special reason that if $p$ divides the order of $H$, that a semisimple $H$ representation would also be a semisimple $G$ representation?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can use the usual averaging argument for proving Maschke's theorem (just take the average over coset representatives of $H$ instead of over all elements of $G$)

Comment: @Jug: Yes you can do it that way if you are careful!

Comment: Given that this implies Maschke's theorem jug's idea is probably the way to go.

Comment: (12.8) in Aschbacher's book "Finite Group Theory" (directly before Maschke's theorem) proves the statement for $H$ a $p$-Sylow (considering also (12.6)). If someone feels like, please expand it into an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Expanded form of the answers from the comments.)

A module is semisimple iff every submodule has a direct complement.

Aschbacher's Finite Group Theory on pages [39](http://books.google.com/books?id=BprbtnlI6HEC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39)-[40](http://books.google.com/books?id=BprbtnlI6HEC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40) proves that if *U* is a sub FG-module of *V* and *U* has an FP-module direct complement, then it has an FG-module direct complement where *P* is a Sylow *p*-subgroup of *G*.  The argument is an averaging argument as described.

Since *H* has index coprime to *p*, *H* contains a Sylow *p*-subgroup *P* of *G*.  Every semisimple FH-module is also semisimple as an FP-module (or just replace *n* in Aschbacher's proof with $[G:P]$ and allow $P=H$ to be any subgroup of index coprime to *p*), and so Aschbacher's result answers your question.

---

The same proof is phrased in more complicated language on pages [70](http://books.google.com/books?id=cezF63340GAC&pg=PA70),
[71](http://books.google.com/books?id=cezF63340GAC&pg=PA71), and
[72](http://books.google.com/books?id=cezF63340GAC&pg=PA72) of Benson's Representations and Cohomology Part 1.

A module is called relatively *H*-projective if *G*-module homomorphisms that split as *H*-module homomorphisms also split as *G*-module homomorphisms.  In other words, you just want to show that every *G*-module is relatively *H*-projective when $[G:H]$ is invertible in the ring, which is Corollary 3.6.9.

Comment: This is given as an exercise in Isaacs's CT and Curtis–Reiner, and when H=1 it is proven in many texts (Isaacs, Curtis–Reiner, Gorenstein, Huppert, Weintraub, Hilton).

Comment: Alperin's Local Rep Theory and the two-volume Curtis–Reiner book also give the relative projective proof. @user32134, let me know if you want google links to those proofs. Alperin's is pretty easy to read (page 66). The two-volume C-R is more like Benson's.