# Group representation is semisimple iff restriction to subgroup of finite index is semisimple

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $\pi: G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$ be an abstract representation of $G$, for $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over a field of characteristic zero.  Let $H$ be a subgroup of finite index of $G$.  Is it true that $\pi$ is semisimple if and only if $\pi|_H$ is semisimple?

Comment: It is true when $G$ is abelian, but I have no idea how to tackle to general case...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151347/a-representation-is-semisimple-if-its-restriction-to-a-subgroup-of-index-prime-t

Answer (score 2):

This is Lemma 2.7 of *The Local Langlands Conjecture for $\operatorname{GL}(2)$* by Henniart and Bushnell.

Let $U$ be a $G$-subspace of $V$.  We need to show that $U$ has a $G$-stable complement.  Since $U$ is $H$-stable, and $V$ is semisimple as a representation of $H$, there exists an $H$-stable complement $U'$ of $U$, so $V = U \oplus U'$.  Let $p: V \rightarrow U$ be the projection onto $U$.  This is an $H$-linear map.  Let $g_1, ... , g_n$ be left coset representatives of $H$ in $G$, and define a map $p^G: V \rightarrow U$ by

$$p^G(v) = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \pi(g_i)p(\pi(g_i)^{-1}v)$$

This is clearly a linear transformation.  It is also straightforward to check that it is $G$-linear, and idempotent.  Hence $V$ is the direct sum of $U$ and $\operatorname{Ker}(p^G)$, both $G$-subspaces.

Comment: Note that Bushnell and Henniart uses $V$ is a finitely-generated $H$-representation to show the other direction, so the proof is incomplete.