# Semisimplificity of restriction of representations over finite fields

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, finite-fields, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $H$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Suppose $V$ is a semisimple finite-dimensional representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a finite field of order $p$.

**Question:** Is the restriction $\text{Res}^{G}_{H}V$ of $V$ to $H$ semisimple?

This is the inverse of ploblem [A representation is semisimple if its restriction to a subgroup of index prime to ${\rm Char}(F)$ is semisimple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151347/a-representation-is-semisimple-if-its-restriction-to-a-subgroup-of-index-prime-t). Note that it is true if $H$ is normal in $G$ by Clifford's Theorem. Any comments and reference would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is negative. Assume $n\geq 2$ and $p\geq 5$. Take $G$ to be ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$, $H$ to be subgroup consisting of upper uni-triangular matrices and  $V$ to be the identity automorphism of $G$. Then $V$ is irreducible, but its restriction to $H$ is not semisimple.